# text following half circle shape with css

Tags: html, css, text, shapes

I'm having a problem with the css code that I wrote. I'm trying to make text follow a half circle shape, so the text should be inside of the shape.
My shape looks like this:
[image]

So I'm having multiple problems, actually...

- The half circle isn't sharp and doesn't connect with the other borders.
- Text won't follow the shape, because the shape is made up of two different components.

Does anyone know how to solve my css problems?
Here is my code (css):

```
.inversePair {
    border: 1px solid saddlebrown;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    text-align: center;
}
#b {
    width: 90%;
    border-right: none;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#b:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 3px solid saddlebrown;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="b" class="inversePair"></div>
```

Comment: You won't be able to solve that problem in pure CSS, unless you know exactly what content you want to put there, and can calculate the width of each containing element for the text and mark that up in the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box and half circle can be created with a div tag. The circle can be clipped to show the left part only. The text letters can be rotated. They follow a circular path though.

```html
<style>
  #box,
  #c {
    border: 1px solid #a9703a;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #efdcad;
  }
  #box {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #c {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px, 150px, 400px, 0px);
  }
  #text {
    transform: rotate(-150deg);
  }
  #text span {
    font-size: 26px;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -310px;
    left: -100px;
  }
  #t1 {
    transform: rotate(6deg);
  }
  #t2 {
    transform: rotate(12deg);
  }
  #t3 {
    transform: rotate(18deg);
  }
  #t4 {
    transform: rotate(24deg);
  }
  #t5 {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  #t6 {
    transform: rotate(36deg);
  }
  #t7 {
    transform: rotate(42deg);
  }
  #t8 {
    transform: rotate(48deg);
  }
  #t9 {
    transform: rotate(54deg);
  }
  #t10 {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
  #t11 {
    transform: rotate(66deg);
  }
  #t12 {
    transform: rotate(72deg);
  }
  #t13 {
    transform: rotate(78deg);
  }
  #t14 {
    transform: rotate(84deg);
  }
  #t15 {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  #t16 {
    transform: rotate(96deg);
  }
  #t17 {
    transform: rotate(102deg);
  }
  #t18 {
    transform: rotate(108deg);
  }
  #t19 {
    transform: rotate(114deg);
  }
  #t20 {
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
</style>


<div id="box">
  <div id="c">
  </div>
  <div id="text">

    <span id="t1">T</span>
    <span id="t2">e</span>
    <span id="t3">x</span>
    <span id="t4">t</span>
    <span id="t5"></span>
    <span id="t6">t</span>
    <span id="t7">i</span>
    <span id="t8">t</span>
    <span id="t9">l</span>
    <span id="t10">e</span>
    <span id="t11"></span>
    <span id="t12">g</span>
    <span id="t13">o</span>
    <span id="t14">e</span>
    <span id="t15">s</span>
    <span id="t16"></span>
    <span id="t17">h</span>
    <span id="t18">e</span>
    <span id="t19">r</span>
    <span id="t20">e</span>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got stuck with this for days, this is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make curved text *that easily* with css, but you might be interested in this article though : https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Using css transform: rotate(); and separating each letter into a span.

But once again, I'm not sure that it's a good idea, maybe an image would be a much cleaner option this time.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for answering, DavicC gave a complete solution, but thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries, DavicC's answer is way better :) Glad it worked !